# Why is there an underscore before the Yii-2 framework's auto generated views (gii)?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm learning Yii2 and experimenting with Yii2's Gii. It automatically generates _form.php and _search.php. I'm trying to figure out Why does Gii adds an underscore before these files. Is this just a filenaming convention or is there any clear logic behind this?

Comment: Its like partials and used by normal view in $this->render.

Comment: does it mean that  we can't render a view within another view without having a leading underscore in its filename?

Comment: no, its just a naming convention

Comment: Nobody can upvote for himself... on S.O: is not a bugs .. is simply honest.

Comment: Like @Szymon say the _ it's only a well know common naming convention for render partial element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Yii a file with an underscore is usually rendered as a [partial file](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail).

For instance `_form.php` is partially rendered from within the create or update files.